# Validate data entry fields before OnChange event in a TabCtl

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to validate required fields are filled on a page before going to another page in Access.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub TabCtlTest_Change()
       If MsgBox("Would you like complete the form?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Complete Form") = vbYes Then
            If IsFormValidated = False Then
                MsgBox "Please fill all mandatory highlighted fields."
            End If
           'Cancel = True
       End If
End Sub
```

I want to validate the required fields before going to another page.  There are six pages in the tab control.  The existing code validates as soon as I click on another page but, I want to validate before leaving the existing page.

Comment: So there are not subforms on tab pages? Think will have to call a procedure from a control.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher, Possibly OP is using tab control to organize fields of a single table that form is bound to. Something I have certainly done. I don't see a subform as a 'replacement' for tab control. Perhaps you are thinking of a Navigation Form.

Comment: @June7 Isn't it the standart practice to replace the tabs by a subform, as all tabs are loaded at once what is slower than loading only the actual needed tab in the subform? I don't use that but heard of (and makes sense to me):

Comment: Your idea could be applied if there is a master/child (form/subform) arrangement involved. If there is only one table with a lot of fields then a tab control can arrange them into groups so screen space is consolidated.

Comment: @June7 I don't see problems with only one table. Just one form for each tab with the needed controls. load if needed. Subform is completly independent from mainform(unbound contains only buttons to simulate change tab). If only one table, you can reuse old subforms recordset and apply it to the new loaded subform.

Comment: @June7 Would it be easier if I created subforms in the tabs?  Would it make check the controls easier?

Comment: Since this is not a master/dependent record arrangement, using multiple subforms bound to same table as main form would introduce other issues. Have you tried answer by jbud?

Comment: @June7 I have tried it and it's working exactly they way I want therefore, I'm going another route.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no event to prevent leaving the current tab page.

You'll need to build a custom flow to take the user back to the "invalidated" page.

Still using the `Change` event you can go back to the previous page.

Define two helper variables at the top of the module to store if we have a validation error and have been sent back.

```
Dim ValidationError As Boolean
Dim SentBack As Boolean
```

The Change Event fires after the page has already changed to the next page.

So you will be effectively sending the user back to the previous page using

`Me.TabCtlTest = Me.TabCtlTest - 1`

which will fire the Change Event again, so we use the variable `ValidationError` to track if we already been sent back by the code. This will prevent an infinite loop.

```
Private Sub TabCtlTest_Change()

    If SentBack Then
        SentBack = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If MsgBox("Would you like complete the form?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Complete Form") = vbYes Then
         If IsFormValidated = False Then
         
            ValidationError = True
            
            If ValidationError Then
                ValidationError = False
                SentBack = True
                If Me.TabCtlTest = 0 Then
                    Me.TabCtlTest = Me.TabCtlTest
                Else
                    Me.TabCtlTest = Me.TabCtlTest - 1
                End If
            End If
            
            MsgBox "Please fill all mandatory highlighted fields."
         End If

    End If
    
End Sub
```

Please see the doc for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/controls/refer-to-tab-control-objects-in-vba